# Use hyperlink to target first class only

Tags: html

```
<a href=".test">Test</a>
<div class="test">Content........</div><div class="test">Content........</div>
```

Currently this is simplify code. When I click the link, it will do something to the class test. However, I only need to target the first class. I know CSS can do something like :first-class, but this is not what I want. Is there anyway to do something like `<a href=".test:firt-class">`??

Comment: when you say first class, do you mean the first element with that class?

Comment: `a + .test` is the selector you can use but it will be generic. You should learn selectors first before getting into all this. Also, you will have to use JavaScript to attach any action on the desired element.

Comment: @DBS, first element of div test class

Answer (score 1):

You should use ID's instead of classes in order to achieve this. Because all of the sections should have an unique ID and because it is supported far better than classes inside of an `<a href="">`.

Do the following:

```
<a href="#target1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#target2">Link 2</a>
<div id="target1">Target 1 content here!</div>
<div id="target2">And target 2 content over here.</div>
```

If in your case you only need to point to the first link, you can use unique ID's to achieve this easily.

Comment: problem is I do not know how to edit class or add id

Comment: You can add the ID to the HTML as I did in my answer, and in order to modify that with CSS, you can simply do `#target1 { color: red; font-weight: 700; }`, or do you mean to do something else with the class/id besides CSS-styling?

Answer (score -1):

Use J-query :

```
HTML :: 
<a class="test" href="#">target 1</a>
<a class="test" href="#">target 2</a>

JQUERY :: 
$( ".test:first").css( "font-style", "italic");
$( ".test:first").css( "font-weight", "bold" );
```

**the fiddle is : https://jsfiddle.net/intelsoftware/u0pw2ftk/**
take a look at : https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/